# fill up a matrix one random cell at a time

Tags: r, matrix, while-loop

I am filling a 10x10 martix (`mat`) randomly until `sum(mat) == 100`

I wrote the following.... (`i = 2` for another reason not specified here but i kept it at `2` to be consistent with my actual code)

```
 mat <- matrix(rep(0, 100), nrow = 10)
 mat[1,]  <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
 mat[2,]  <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
 mat[3,]  <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
 mat[4,]  <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
 mat[5,]  <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
 mat[6,]  <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
 mat[7,]  <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 mat[8,]  <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 mat[9,]  <- c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 mat[10,] <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

 i <- 2

 set.seed(129)

 while( sum(mat) < 100 ) {
 # pick random cell
 rnum <- sample( which(mat < 1), 1 )
 mat[rnum] <- 1
 ##
 print(paste0("i =", i))
 print(paste0("rnum =", rnum))
 print(sum(mat))
 i = i + 1
 }
```

For some reason when `sum(mat) == 99` there are several steps extra...I would assume that once `i = 91` the `while` would stop but it continues past this. Can somone explain what I have done wrong...

If I change the while condition to

```
while( sum(mat) < 100 & length(which(mat < 1)) > 0 )
```

the issue remains..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?sample`

```
Arguments:

       x: Either a vector of one or more elements from which to choose,
          or a positive integer.  See ‘Details.’

...

     If ‘x’ has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of ‘is.numeric’) and
     ‘x >= 1’, sampling _via_ ‘sample’ takes place from ‘1:x’.  _Note_
     that this convenience feature may lead to undesired behaviour when
     ‘x’ is of varying length in calls such as ‘sample(x)’.  See the
     examples.
```

In other words, if `x` in `sample(x)` is of length 1, `sample` returns a random number from `1:x`. This happens towards the end of your loop, where there is just one 0 left in your matrix and one index is returned by `which(mat < 1)`.

Comment: Happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is equivalent to randomly ordering the indices of a matrix that are equal to 0. You can do this in one line with `sample(which(mat < 1))`. I suppose if you wanted to get exactly the same sort of output, you might try something like:

```
set.seed(144)
idx <- sample(which(mat < 1))
for (i in seq_along(idx)) {
  print(paste0("i =", i))
  print(paste0("rnum =", idx[i]))
  print(sum(mat)+i)
}
# [1] "i =1"
# [1] "rnum =5"
# [1] 11
# [1] "i =2"
# [1] "rnum =70"
# [1] 12
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The iteration repeats on level 99 because `sample()` behaves very differently when the first parameter is a vector of length 1 and when it is greater than 1. When it is length 1, it assumes you a random number from 1 to that number. When it has length >1, then you get a random number from that vector.

Compare

```
sample(c(99,100),1)
```

and

```
sample(c(100),1)
```

Of course, this is an inefficient way of filling your matrix. As @josilber pointed out, a single call to `sample` could do everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from how `sample` and `which` do the sampling when you have only a single '0' value left.

For example, do this:

```
mat <- matrix(rep(1, 100), nrow = 10)
```

Now you have a matrix of all 1's. Now lets make two numbers 0:

```
mat[15]<-0
mat[18]<-0
```

and then sample

```
sample(which(mat<1))
[1] 18 15
```

by adding a `size=1` argument you get one or the other

now lets try this:

```
mat[18]<-1
sample(which(mat<1))
[1]  3 13  8  2  4 14 11  9 10  5 15  7  1 12  6
```

Oops, you did not get `[1] 15` . Instead what happens in only a single integer (15 in this case) is passed to`sample`. When you do `sample(x)` and `x` is an integer, it gives you a sample from `1:x` with the integers in random order.